# How to configure FileBeat and Logstash to add XML Files in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I'm a beginner here. My own problem is to configure FileBeat and Logstash to add XML Files in Elasticsearch on CentOS 7.
I have already install the last version of filebeat, logstash, elasticsearch and Kibana, with the plug-in "elasticsearch-head" in standalone to see inside elasticsearch. And to test my installation, i have successfully add simple log file from CentOS system (/var/log/messages), and see it inside elasticsearch-head plug-in (6 index and 26 shards):
[This is a viex of my elasticsearch-head plug-in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck7fZ.png)

And now, next step is to add log from XML file. After reading the documentation, i have configure filebeat and logstash. All services are running, and i try the command "touch /mes/AddOf.xml" to try to active an filebeat event, and forward log to logstash (AddOf.xml is my log file).

My XML data structure is like this for one log event :

```
<log4j:event logger="ServiceLogger" timestamp="1494973209812" level="INFO" thread="QueueWorker_1_38a0fec5-7c7f-46f5-a87a-9134fff1b493">
    <log4j:message>Traitement du fichier \\ifs-app-01\Interfaces_MES\AddOf\ITF_MES_01_01_d2bef200-3a85-11e7-1ab5-9a50967946c3.xml</log4j:message>
    <log4j:properties>
        <log4j:data name="log4net:HostName" value="MES-01" />
        <log4j:data name="log4jmachinename" value="MES-01" />
        <log4j:data name="log4net:Identity" value="" />
        <log4j:data name="log4net:UserName" value="SOFRADIR\svc_mes_sf" />
        <log4j:data name="LogName" value="UpdateOperationOf" />
        <log4j:data name="log4japp" value="MES_SynchroService.exe" />
    </log4j:properties>
    <log4j:locationInfo class="MES_SynchroService.Core.FileManager" method="TraiteFichier" file="C:\src\MES_PROD\MES_SynchroService\Core\FileManager.cs" line="47" />
</log4j:event>
```

My filebeat configuration like this (/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml):

```
filebeat.prospectors:

# Each - is a prospector. Most options can be set at the prospector level, so
# you can use different prospectors for various configurations.
# Below are the prospector specific configurations.
- input_type: log

  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
    - /mes/*.xml

  document_type: message

  ### Multiline options

  # Mutiline can be used for log messages spanning multiple lines. This is common
  # for Java Stack Traces or C-Line Continuation

  # The regexp Pattern that has to be matched. The example pattern matches all lines starting with [
  multiline.pattern: ^<log4j:event

  # Defines if the pattern set under pattern should be negated or not. Default is false.
  multiline.negate: true

  # Match can be set to "after" or "before". It is used to define if lines should be append to a pattern
  # that was (not) matched before or after or as long as a pattern is not matched based on negate.
  # Note: After is the equivalent to previous and before is the equivalent to to next in Logstash
  multiline.match: after

#================================ Outputs =====================================

# Configure what outputs to use when sending the data collected by the beat.
# Multiple outputs may be used.

#----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]

  # Optional SSL. By default is off.
  # List of root certificates for HTTPS server verifications
  ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"]

  # Certificate for SSL client authentication
  #ssl.certificate: "/etc/pki/client/cert.pem"

  # Client Certificate Key
  #ssl.key: "/etc/pki/client/cert.key"
```

My input logstash configuration (/etc/logstash/conf.d/01-beats-input.conf) :

```
input {
 beats {
 port => 5044
 ssl => true
 ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
 ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
 }
}
```

My filter logstash configuration (/etc/logstash/conf.d/01-beats-filter.conf) :

```
filter 
{
    xml 
    {
        source => "message"
        xpath => 
        [
            "/log4j:event/log4j:message/text()", "messageMES"
        ]
        store_xml => true
        target => "doc"
    }
}
```

My output logstash configuration (/etc/logstash/conf.d/01-beats-output.conf) :

```
output {
 elasticsearch {
 hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
 sniffing => true
 manage_template => false
 index => "mes_log"
 document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
 }
}
```

But when i try the command "touch /mes/AddOf.xml", or add manually an event log in AddOf.xml, i don't see a new index with events log from XML file in elasticsearch.

I have see documentation for XML plug-in for logstash ([here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-xml.html)), but i don't now if i need to install something ? Or maybe I'm not doing the right thing for filebeat to send the logs to logstash ?

I'm very involved and motivated to learn about ELK stack. Thank you in advance for your expertise and help. I would be grateful ! :)

Comment: Have you checked the log of each system during your process? If you are not seeing anything on ES, maybe it's just a problem linking logstash to ES. Do you need some authentication? Try to check `user`, `password`, `ssl` and `cacert` parameters, in case you need them (in your last snippet). You can check if your data comes to logstash printing the results directly to the shell: if they appear, the problem is with the linking. just use as output `output{ stdout { codec => rubydebug } }`

Comment: Hi. I have unable ssl certificate finaly i don't need it. I don't use user or password for ES. That was an filter problem with the xml namespace. But it's not totaly resolved (see messages under this one).

Answer (score 0):

In your filebeat config, the regex for `multiline.pattern` probably should be in single-quotes:

```
multiline.pattern: '^<log4j:event'
```

Comment: Tanks for help, that is true for single-quotes ! But I'm always at the same point. A test idea to find out if the problem comes from filebeat or logstash ?

Comment: You can run both filebeat and logstash in the debug mode. ./filebeat -c filebeat.yml -e -d "*" and bin/logstash -f path/to/logstash.conf --log.level debug.

Comment: Tanks, with logstash debug commande i have find an filter error with the xml namespace (log4j). Now the filter work with : 'remove_namespaces => true' and the xpath '/event/message/text()". But output tags show an parsing error : '_xmlparsefailure'. I'm sure this silent error is from the namespace again, but parsing work, in my "xpath_message" field i get the message. What do you think about that ? It's strange, the issue is here and work : https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-xml/issues/10, but error tag stay.

Comment: There is a very nice tool to debug events in: https://github.com/ugosan/docker-logstash-http-debug